# Auto Generate Id in a pre-define formate in springboot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application where I want to auto-generate the table Id (In MySQL) of my entity in a predefined format.

The format is like "AK"+6 digits (eg: AK000001, AK000002, AK000003...AK999999).

I am using strategy = GenerationType.AUTO

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

Please help me to auto-generate the Id of predefine format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support using an auto-increment for this. See my answer to [adding a kind of auto increment column to a mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812494/adding-a-kind-of-auto-increment-column-to-a-mysql-table/44812826#44812826)

You will have to generate the id values yourself in Java code, and insert them explicitly. This means you have to use a number generator that is thread-safe and resistant to race conditions. If you have multiple app servers, it will have to be a service. For example, Memcached has an atomic number generation command.